# Is there a way to create an circlular design inside a rectangle and adjust the circumference?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx

I am trying to create something similar to a semi circle inside a rectangle something like this, the ellipse in the background.

[expected design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXely.png)

I am able to implement the circle inside the rectangle but couldn't find a way to cut out the extra part of the ellipse, can someone please help me with achieving the required design?

[achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/admjF.png)

```
.rectangle {
    height: 110px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border-radius: 9px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```
position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;  
    left: 100px;
```

Comment: As the circles are just decoration there is no need for them to be in the DOM so look into background with radial-gradient and positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You want to hide the part of the circle that overflows the rectangle

You can do this by setting `overflow: hidden;` on the rectangle.

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 110px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   .rectangle{
 height: 110px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: #313131;
    border-radius: 9px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.circle{
position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 93%;
    height: 95%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #404040;
}
.circle-border{
          border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    right: -129px;
    top: -6px;
    width: 41%;
    height: 70%;
    border: 2px solid #404040;
}

    <div class="rectangle">
<div class="circle-border">
    
    <div class="circle">
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).